# Overleaf not compiling?

Tags: overleaf

Hi I was using overleaf but at a certain time it just stop compiling, showing me this:
[image]

like my whole project depends on that and now I am stuck.
Most of the errors are like : You can't use `the character 2' after \the.
Any ideas??

the part of the code

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}

\newcommand{\MS}{{\large M\raisebox{0.4ex}{\footnotesize S} $\sim$ {{I\hspace*{0.12cm}\raisebox{0.566ex}{S}\hspace*{0.155cm}I}}} - FP \emph{B\'eni Mellal}}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-55pt}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-40pt}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-13pt}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{60pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{90pt}
\addtolength{\footskip}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\headsep}{25pt}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Cr�er des liens et des signets
\hypersetup{    
colorlinks=true, %colorise les liens
breaklinks=true, %permet le retour � la ligne dans les liens trop longs
urlcolor= blue, %couleur des hyperliens
linkcolor= blue,    %couleur des liens internes
citecolor=blue, %couleur des r�f�rences
%pdftitle={Rapport de stage}, %informations apparaissant dans
%pdfauthor={Anonyme}, %les informations du document
%pdfsubject={Simulation}    %sous Acrobat.
}
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, lmodern, eurosym}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}
\usepackage[french]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{listings}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{5}
\setlength{\mtcindent}{24pt}
\renewcommand{\mtcfont}{\small\rm}
\renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\small\bf}
\def\contentsname{Table des Mati\`{e}res}

\pagestyle{empty}

\definecolor{blueumi}{rgb}{0.00,0.48,0.62}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{1pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{black}\hrule}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\color{black}\hrule}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}


\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames, xcdraw]{xcolor}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\chapter{Présentation des methodologies et outils du test de pénétration réseau}
\minitoc
%\minilof
%\minilot
\newpage
\vspace*{1cm}
\vskip1cm

\section*{Introduction}
\subsection{Penetration Testing Execution Standard (PTES)}



\noindent Parmi les points forts en PTES on trouve :
% avantages

\begin{longtable}[c]{ |p{7cm}|p{8cm}| } 

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Avantages}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Justification}}} \\
\hline

\endfirsthead

\hline
Offrir le support nécessaire au testeur avant exécution      & PTES définit avec soin toute planification qui doit être définie et donne une description plus pratique des activités à réaliser.   \\ \hline
Modélisation de menaces & PTES est la seule à introduire la modélisation de menaces dans les étapes du test d’intrusion. Cette étape permet au pentester de prioriser les vulnérabilités et du coup attaquer de manière plus sophistiquée.\\ \hline
Fournir des détails techniques & La norme PTES est accompagnée d’un manuel technique qui détail les principaux aspects techniques et précise les outils utilisés.\\ \hline 
\caption{Les avantages de la méthodologie PTES}
\label{tab:avantages ptes}
\end{longtable}
\noindent PTES d'un seul inconvénient majeur \cite{макаренко2020анализ}:\\
% limites
\begin{longtable}{|p{7cm}|p{8cm}| } 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Limites}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Justification}}} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
Evolution technologique & Les détails techniques présentés par PTES deviennent rapidement obsolètes à cause du développement informatique à titre d’exemple la sortie de nouvelles plateformes et logiciels, à cet égard les développeurs n’ont pas toujours le temps de les tenir à jour. \\ \hline
\caption{Les limites de la méthodologie PTES }
\label{tab:limites ptes}
\end{longtable}


\section*{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Copy your `main.tex` into a new file `mwe.tex`, and copy one chapter into it (delete the `\input` or `\include` commands) and try, if the error still exist. If it still exist, make the capter shorter and compile again. Show this shorter file in your question (copy and paste it into it).

Comment: here it is i did it this is the part

Comment: The big problem is `\cite{макаренко2020анализ}`; try using ASCII characters only for the key. You should also change `\renewcommand{\headsep}{25pt}` to `\setlength{\headsep}{25pt}`. Load `xcolor` only once, with the options you need, much earlier e.g. just after `\documentclass{book}`. The `hyperref` package and `\hypersetup` should be loaded last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your code, resulting that the code is not compilable ... Let's have a look on it:

- Do not use `geometry`, if you use `\addtolength{\topmargin}{-55pt}` etc. Or the better way: Use `geometry` with proper options and delete your manual settings with `\addtolength{\topmargin}{-55pt}` ...
- Load packages only once (several packages you loaded twice or more) and respect the order of loading packages as I did in the follwoing MWE. For example I loaded `tikz` and `hyperref` last ...
- Change your used `\cite{макаренко2020анализ}` to something like `\cite{test}`, that means use only ASCII characters for the key of your bib entry.
- Do you realy need all that loaded packages? If not delete that one you do not use in your document.

Compiling MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}

\newcommand{\MS}{{\large M\raisebox{0.4ex}{\footnotesize S} $\sim$ {{I\hspace*{0.12cm}\raisebox{0.566ex}{S}\hspace*{0.155cm}I}}} - FP \emph{B\'eni Mellal}}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-55pt}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-40pt}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-13pt}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{60pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{90pt}
\addtolength{\footskip}{12pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{25pt} % <========================== \renewcommand{\headsep}{25pt}


\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, lmodern, eurosym}
\usepackage{graphicx} % <======================= deleted option [pdftex]
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}
\usepackage[french]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{listings}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{5}
\setlength{\mtcindent}{24pt}
\renewcommand{\mtcfont}{\small\rm}
\renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\small\bf}
\def\contentsname{Table des Mati\`{e}res}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{1pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{black}\hrule}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\color{black}\hrule}

\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{geometry} % <==============================================
\usepackage[table, svgnames, xcdraw]{xcolor}

\definecolor{blueumi}{rgb}{0.00,0.48,0.62}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{hyperref} % Cr�er des liens et des signets
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,             %colorise les liens
  breaklinks=true,             %permet le retour � la ligne dans les liens trop longs
  urlcolor= blue,              %couleur des hyperliens
  linkcolor= blue,             %couleur des liens internes
  citecolor=blue,              %couleur des r�f�rences
% pdftitle={Rapport de stage}, %informations apparaissant dans
% pdfauthor={Anonyme},         %les informations du document
% pdfsubject={Simulation}      %sous Acrobat.
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\chapter{Présentation des methodologies et outils du test de pénétration réseau}
\minitoc
%\minilof
%\minilot
\newpage
\vspace*{1cm}
\vskip1cm

\section*{Introduction}
\subsection{Penetration Testing Execution Standard (PTES)}



\noindent Parmi les points forts en PTES on trouve :
% avantages

\begin{longtable}[c]{ |p{7cm}|p{8cm}| } 

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Avantages}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Justification}}} \\
\hline

\endfirsthead

\hline
Offrir le support nécessaire au testeur avant exécution      & PTES définit avec soin toute planification qui doit être définie et donne une description plus pratique des activités à réaliser.   \\ \hline
Modélisation de menaces & PTES est la seule à introduire la modélisation de menaces dans les étapes du test d’intrusion. Cette étape permet au pentester de prioriser les vulnérabilités et du coup attaquer de manière plus sophistiquée.\\ \hline
Fournir des détails techniques & La norme PTES est accompagnée d’un manuel technique qui détail les principaux aspects techniques et précise les outils utilisés.\\ \hline 
\caption{Les avantages de la méthodologie PTES}
\label{tab:avantages ptes}
\end{longtable}
\noindent PTES d'un seul inconvénient majeur \cite{test}:\\ % <=======================
% limites
\begin{longtable}{|p{7cm}|p{8cm}| } 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Limites}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Justification}}} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
Evolution technologique & Les détails techniques présentés par PTES deviennent rapidement obsolètes à cause du développement informatique à titre d’exemple la sortie de nouvelles plateformes et logiciels, à cet égard les développeurs n’ont pas toujours le temps de les tenir à jour. \\ \hline
\caption{Les limites de la méthodologie PTES }
\label{tab:limites ptes}
\end{longtable}


\section*{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: thank you a lot it was the article in the biblio and the big problem in the packages

Comment: @DidyouknowTHAT You are welcome!